# BAM Gadget tool

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I created a gadget with the gadget tool connecting to my local postgresql DB... Everything worked perfectly but when I add the gadget to my gadget dashboard it shows nothing.
This is my gadget route:

```
/registry/resource/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.bam.gadgetgen/gadgetgen/tabla.xml
```

This is the console error:

```
    Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql

btw, i have read all the related documentation without success 

Log

    Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
OK
OK
OK
[2013-10-07 16:56:09,420]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.service.GCInspector} -  GC for PS Scavenge: 375 ms for 1 collections, 95658024 used; max is 954466304
[2013-10-07 16:56:09,516]  WARN {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db.DatabaseHostObject} -  Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db.DatabaseHostObject.jsConstructor(DatabaseHostObject.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor295.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:160)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:417)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.construct(BaseFunction.java:328)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2266)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0._c0(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag:4)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0.call(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0.call(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0.exec(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:441)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:191)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:269)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 44 more
[2013-10-07 16:56:09,577] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql (/gadgetgen//tabla.jag#4)
[2013-10-07 16:56:09,605] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql (/gadgetgen//tabla.jag#4)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql (/gadgetgen//tabla.jag#4)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:446)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:191)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:269)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql (/gadgetgen//tabla.jag#4)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:175)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:417)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.construct(BaseFunction.java:328)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2266)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0._c0(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag:4)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0.call(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0.call(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.gadgetgen.c0.exec(/gadgetgen//tabla.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:441)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error connecting to the database : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/wso2bam_postgresql
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db.DatabaseHostObject.jsConstructor(DatabaseHostObject.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor295.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:160)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db.DatabaseHostObject.jsConstructor(DatabaseHostObject.java:144)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 44 more
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
Hadoop job information for null: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2013-10-07 16:56:12,979 null map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-10-07 16:56:18,996 null map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the driver .jar to $BAM_HOME/repository/components/lib directory? And were you able to see the data in the preview when you are creating the gadget in gadget-gen wizard?

Please make sure above two, and provide the entire stack trace rather only the error message.

Comment: hello, yep i have the driver located in the proper directory...and yes i'm able to preview the table/bar...btw what do you call "entire stack" the full log after running the .sh script?...i'm very noob to BAM, i have read the documentation and i'm trying to retrieve data from the DB to create a simple KPI...thanks in advance

Comment: The error stacktrace means the whole exception trace. You have only included the first line of the stacktrace. Include the whole exception  trace.

Comment: Hello @Ragavan, sry for the delay, i have updated the question with the log. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Sinthuja, sry for the delay, i have updated the question with the log. Thanks

Comment: What jdbc driver you are using? Java version? Since postgresql is case sensitive, don't mix cases in table names or column names.

Comment: Hello @Ragavan as suggested by google i'm using this one http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html it's a simple table i'm just testing with a simple query "select row from table" i'm able to see the preview just fine...

Answer (score 0):

In the jag file created for the gadget in //repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/gadgetgen there will be a variable 'config' with empty {}. Change it to

```
var config = {"driverClassName":"org.postgresql.Driver"};
```